# GET when "working folder contains a writable copy" has the Do you want to "Leave this file" radio button disabled. How do I enable it?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

VSS 2005.  I'm doing a GET of my project on a recently new PC with a SS database on a local server.  Whenever I do a GET where I've made some local modifications (i.e. the files are NOT readonly), I am getting the proper VSS dialog "Your working folder contains a writable copy of blah blah blah" with the 4 Do you want to... options.

However, the first radio button *Leave this file?* is disabled.  Why is that and how do I get it to be enabled (this is what I want to do)?

Note: the "Replace your local file" and "Check Out the file" radio button options are both enabled.  The "Check Out the local version and merge" is DISabled, but I don't need to do that, but this bit of information may be helpful in the diagnosis.

Comment: Please check the settings in your [SourceSafe Options -> Local Files](http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/sourcesafe/get-latest.html) tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MSDN DVD had an old build, and I guess Windows Update doesn't bother checking VSS.

Anyway, there was a patch for SS 2005.  Here's the article discussing the download:
http://support.microsoft.com/?id=943847